# How to define UserType' s name globally in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, typedef, usertype

It's possible to use @TypeDefs annotation to define short type name for a UserType. But how to define it for entire application?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a basic value type name (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-types-basictypes) to your UserType class, making that class the substitute of the standard class.

For example:

```
<typedef name="string" 
      class="com.foo.hibernate.userType.NewStringUserType"></typedef>
```